# How to hide the gray/white areas in mapView in android

Tags: android, android-mapview

In the following screenshot you can see a white area (highlighted by red) appearing by default in every mapview. I know that the mapView in android has this default behavior but when the native Google Maps app is launched in the device, it doesnt show the white area. I would like to see that behavior. But i am out of options. Should there be any scroll listener on the map which will stop the panning over white areas. Any help is appreciable.

Thanks,

[image: Check the highlighted area in this image]

Answer (score 0):

> In the following screenshot you can see a white area (highlighted by red) appearing by default in every mapview.

It does not appear "by default in every mapview". [This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk), for example, does not have these areas, at least at reasonable zoom levels.

It is likely that your problem is purely at a zoom level of 1, due to the aspect ratio of the Mercator projection. It has been years since I bothered with a zoom level of 1.

> but when the native Google Maps app is launched in the device, it doesnt show the white area

That is because the Google Maps application does not start out at a zoom level of 1. If, however, you pinch-to-zoom to get to its lowest zoom level, then pan around, you will see those white spaces above and below the map. Again, this is most likely due to the aspect ratio of the Mercator projection.

> Should there be any scroll listener on the map which will stop the panning over white areas.

I doubt it.

Comment: Yes the sample application does not show the white areas initially but when zooomed out completely i can see the white areas. But the same google map does not show the white areas when you open the Google Maps application in an android device(even if you zoom out completely). The mercator projection issue might be there but any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: @Vansi: "But the same google map does not show the white areas when you open the Google Maps application in an android device(even if you zoom out completely)." -- yes, it does, as tested on my Galaxy Nexus. You need to pan around to see the white areas, just as you need to pan around to see portions of the map, as the Google Maps application does not zoom out as far as what you have shown in the screenshot. "The mercator projection issue might be there but any ideas on how to solve this." -- you can move to a different planet, one that was designed to fit the aspect ratio of a phone.